# as3 calling a function in another class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, function, package

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [as3 Main-Timline calling a function from a class loaded from Child.swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442115/as3-main-timline-calling-a-function-from-a-class-loaded-from-child-swf)

I asked this question already but I am not getting any responses so I am triming it down to make it less scary. I just need ONE LINE of code.

**What code do I use to call a function in another CLASS package?** My code is calling from the main timeline and the class is loaded from a child loaded by the main timeline.

Here is the code that is close but does not work:

```
    Content = TheContent.content as MovieClip;
    pContent = Content as Object;
    addChild(TheContent);

    var OSS:String = "device";
    trace(pContent); ////makes contact with classs but comes out as: [object pContent]
    pContent.GetOnlineStatus(OSS); ///// HOW DO I GET THIS TO CALL FUNCTION
```

TypeError: Error #1006: GetOnlineStatus is not a function.

Here is my old post with more details: [as3 Main-Timline calling a function from a class loaded from Child.swf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442115/as3-main-timline-calling-a-function-from-a-class-loaded-from-child-swf)